# z-order of objects

Tags: pstricks

When I draw objects in PSTricks, objects are placed in the order I draw them, i.e. objects that appear later in the picture hide those that appear earlier, for example here:

```
\begin{pspicture}(70,70)
\psframe[fillcolor=green!20,fillstyle=solid](0,0)(30,30)
\psframe[fillcolor=blue!20,fillstyle=solid](10,10)(40,40)
\end{pspicture}
```

the blue square partially hides the green square.

In CSS it is possible to give each object a "z index", such that objects with a larger z-index hide those with a smaller z-index, so for example if I give the green square a z-index of 10 and the blue square a z-index of 0, the green square will hide the blue square no matter in what order they are placed in the document.

Is there a similar option in PSTricks?

(Of course in the above example it is possible to just switch the order of the squares in the picture, but in more complex pictures, with many different objects that some of them come from macros etc., it may be very difficult).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

we can collect such macros with names like `\PST<z>` where `<z>` starts with `0`. First we have to change the behaviour of the backslash to save the complete command sequence:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\makeatletter
\def\addentry#1{\addentry@i#1\@nil}
\begingroup
\catcode`\|=0    %% make the | behave like a backslash
|catcode`\\=12   %% make the \ a normal character
|gdef|addentry@i#1;#2|@nil{|@namedef{PST#1}{#2}}% save #2 as \PST#1
|endgroup
\def\printentries{\printentries@i{0}}
\def\printentries@i#1{%
  \if\@nameuse{PST#1}\relax
  \else
    \@nameuse{PST#1}%
    \printentries@i{\the\numexpr#1+1}%
 \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.1}
\begin{pspicture}(40,40)
\pscircle*[linecolor=magenta,opacity=0.5](20,20){20}
\psframe[fillcolor=green!20,fillstyle=solid](0,0)(30,30)
\psframe[fillcolor=blue!20,fillstyle=solid](10,10)(40,40)
\end{pspicture}
%
\begin{pspicture}(40,40)
\addentry{2;\pscircle*[linecolor=magenta,opacity=0.5](20,20){20}}
\addentry{1;\psframe[fillcolor=green!20,fillstyle=solid](0,0)(30,30)}
\addentry{0;\psframe[fillcolor=blue!20,fillstyle=solid](10,10)(40,40)}
\printentries
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

There is no such option in PSTricks, but the [`pst-ovl`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-ovl) package can be used for a more verbose kind of overlays:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-ovl}
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=0.1}
\begin{pspicture}(40,40)
\begin{overlaybox}
  \psoverlay{two}\psframe[fillcolor=green!20,fillstyle=solid](0,0)(30,30)
  \psoverlay{one}\psframe[fillcolor=blue!20,fillstyle=solid](10,10)(40,40)
\end{overlaybox}%
\putoverlaybox{one}\putoverlaybox{two}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]